# Border for gridview items in android

Tags: android, gridview, border

I displayed image and text in a gridview. i.e. Each item consists of one image and one text. It works fine. But I would like to know how to set the border of each gridview item separately in android.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) create a attrs.xml under res>value folder.

2) Add a resource :

```
<declare-styleable name="Gallery1">
        <attr name="android:galleryItemBackground" />
 </declare-styleable>
```

3) Add following code in your respective activity:

```
TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
int mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(
                    R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
a.recycle();
```

4) then set the `mGalleryItemBackground` as the background of your view. You will get a border outside your view.
For example:

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..I used ur code.But still im having red line error as "styleable cannot resolved".But i've created attr.xml under value folder well.

Comment: sorry dude.. i did a typo.. filename is attrs.xml. Rename the file and then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a customed background by creating your own shape file...

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
    </shape>
```

and then simply add a background to the resource...

```
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape);
```